# Writing files in a Docker Nodejs Image

Tags: node.js, docker, filesystems

I'm building a NodeJS (Express) application off the Node Docker Image and need to generate files through the app. Whenever I run the application outside of Docker my code works and the file shows up as expected, but when `docker-compose up`-ing it the rest of the app works fine but no files are written. The scripts don't throw any errors either so my suspicion is that this is more to do with how Docker manages files within containers.

I've tried two different implementations of my solution too, one using the `fs` library and another generating files using ffmpeg, both with the same results.

I've tried `console.log(__dirname)` to confirm I'm looking in the right directory too but, alas, no luck there.

If it's of any help, I'm working of the Node image and the MySQL image, using Docker-Compose to link the two. I'm also using the PM2 process manager (recommended by a tutorial I was following) in case this can give any other useful info.

Should I be creating some kind of volume for Docker to write files to, or is it as simple as adding a specific library to my application?

Comment: How do you know no files are being written? Can you provide a testable example?

Comment: I've run the application and set up routes which would write a simple text file when pinged. They work when running the app via `npm run` but not when using `docker-compose up`. The files just don't exist, or if they do they're not where expected or anywhere on my machine

Comment: When you run `docker-compose up` you spawn containers. Each container corresponds to a service that is described in your `docker-compose.yml` file. The files will be written inside the Docker container.

Comment: File I/O in Docker generally works fine, though each container has its own isolated filesystem space that gets destroyed at the end of each container's lifetime.  Things that communicate principally via files tend to be harder to run in Docker than they would otherwise, and typically you'd try to design a container to store all of its persistent state "somewhere else" like a database if you can.  Do you have a [mcve] showing what's wrong?

Comment: @sachav That was the issue. Basically a misunderstanding on my end about how Docker containers work. Glad to have bridged that knowledge gap. Adapted my code and re-ran the tests printing out the contents of the container file structure and the files are there! If you upgrade your comment to an answer I'll mark it as resolved. Thanks